# Can I Connect To SQL Server In Xamarin Forms Using WCF

Tags: c#, xamarin

Can I Connect To SQL Server In Xamarin Forms Using WCF
Help Me Please

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask correct questions. Also give this a read on [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Answer is probably "yes"

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'd say 'Definitely, yes.'

Comment: yeah check this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/Application_Fundamentals/Web_Services/

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote a popular person for this:

> *"Yes, we can."*

[Source.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama_presidential_campaign,_2008#Slogan)